# Arlanda airport to center. the cheapest way

Tags: air-travel

While checking websites there are two ways to go central Stockholm from Arlanda airport.
There are 941  or 937 trains.
There is also express. Express is around 30 eur.
But I dont know the 941 or 937 trains. Are they same price? There is no bus also? I think so from this website but I am not sure? [Link here.](https://arlandastockholmairport.com/gt-booking/?clientID=532715&CT=MP&ln=EN&rtLat=59.3303621&rtLng=18.0586789&pickupName=Stockholm%20-%20Airport%20-%20Arlanda&returnName=Stockholms%20Centralstation%20-%20Centralplan%2C%20111%2020%20Stockholm%2C%20Sweden&curr=EUR&residenceID=PL&countryID=SE&elID=421657127924252&pkLat=59.65000000000009&pkLng=17.923999999999978&pickupID=3250&dropoffPID=ChIJyYZWp1ydX0YRrJIvSmxkqgY&ELID=421657127924252&pickupDateTime=2022-07-15T08%3A20%3A00&oneway=true&returnDateTime=2022-07-15T08%3A20%3A00&passengersAges=30&PUF=1&DOF=1&PUR=0&DOR=0#/vehicles)
Can anybody help me?

Comment: https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flygbussarna.se%2Fen%2F%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR0rhkfp76tmhDBgW566JWKNUTTgdeechpTrT_oDGxXho7PY0eMUWT-ZNqE&h=AT3WcXIyWRYruv8v0kYeyubljXIJlVmScp6ZbuipmA5isrm_uUli6XxtFg7tTnGBxdjUVKDivyFER9trcV_BQyhsOUkIg0wBgVB5IGdF-eVjLanknTQnplpCCBjgiDL1BDLo-g   is this bus going to center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the local bus 579 or 583 to Märsta station and take the commuter train from there. This is much cheaper than the airport coach or taking the commuter train directly from Arlanda, the current price is 39 SEK. You can pay by touching your credit card on the reader on the bus and on the train station.

The schedules are available on https://sl.se/, they seem to only be available in Swedish. For instance you can search for a journey from "Arlanda terminal 2 och 3 (Sigtuna)" to "Stockholm City (Stockholm)". The buses leave every 30 minutes and the journey takes a little over one hour.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean this option is cheaper than direct bus which is stated here from airport to central   https://www.flygbussarna.se/en/nya-hallplatslagen-arlanda around 11 euro?

Comment: Yes, the direct bus is 119 SEK if you buy it online in advance and 139 SEK if you buy it at the airport. You can find the prices at https://www.flygbussarna.se/en/prices.

Comment: Thanks. If we buy round trip we can use the ticket for tomorrow to turn back?

Comment: It is a one way ticket only. The local transit tickets are valid for 75 minutes, so you have to get on the train within 75 minutes from that you bought the ticket on the bus. This should be plenty of time. If you use the same credit card both on the bus and on the train you will only pay once, the system will know that you had already bought a ticket on the bus.

Comment: When I went to Stockholm 6 years ago (and I guess this possibility still exists), I bought a 24h ticket at Arlanda, that would also have allowed me to return to Arlanda (I had a train ticket from Stockholm, so there was no point in doing that).

Comment: Yes, that is also a possibility. A 24 hour travel card costs 165 SEK plus that you have to buy the card for 20 SEK. It is also possible to buy the card in the SL app, then you don't need to buy the card.

If you are only going to the airport and back the best option is still to pay on bus with your credit card, but if you plan to do more journeys with public transport a 24 hour travel card might be the best option.

Comment: @ Tobias Linton So, I did not get it. what do you mean by same credit card? So for a person who reach there on 10AM and wants to turn back the day after on 4 pm what is the best option? We can pay inside the bus you mean just once while going and it will be Ok to use it for turning back?! Also, when I want to buy online bus ticket it is written "Ticket is valid for 3 months in any direction" what is that?

Comment: By the way I again checked the website. There is option for round trip. One way is 119SEK and round trip is 189 sek. (https://www.flygbussarna.se/en/checkout#cart) I think this is the best option.

Comment: Flygbussarna is easier than taking the local bus and then the commuter train (which I suggested in my reply), but it is more expensive. However, unless you are on a very tight budget it is probably worth paying 189 SEK to take a bus that goes straight to the city centre.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SJ.se](https://www.sj.se/en/) to look up trains and buses from Arlanda to Stockholm.

Rates vary but the cheapest seems to be the bus at 149 SEK (about 14 EUR). Commuter trains start at 181 SEK, with regional trains at 214 SEK.

Note that Arlanda Express trains depart from Arlanda North or South while the other trains depart from Arlanda Central (know as Arlanda C), under Sky City.

The bus and commuter trains also take a lot longer (up to 48 minutes against 20 for the Express and regional trains).

Comment: https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flygbussarna.se%2Fen%2F%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR0rhkfp76tmhDBgW566JWKNUTTgdeechpTrT_oDGxXho7PY0eMUWT-ZNqE&h=AT3WcXIyWRYruv8v0kYeyubljXIJlVmScp6ZbuipmA5isrm_uUli6XxtFg7tTnGBxdjUVKDivyFER9trcV_BQyhsOUkIg0wBgVB5IGdF-eVjLanknTQnplpCCBjgiDL1BDLo-g                               so can I use this bus? I mean all of these are inside airport right?

Comment: https://www.flygbussarna.se/en/nya-hallplatslagen-arlanda Yes it departs from terminals 2/3 stop 6 and terminal 4 stop 7.

Comment: sorry it is written for round trip whichis 189 sek ""Ticket is valid for 3 months in both directions. Reg. price SEK238."". What is that reg. Pricw 238 sek??? One way is 119 sek round is 189 sek but sth written as i mentioned what is that? If the total price which is 189 is not the final one and 238 will be added then it is better to go one way am I right?

Comment: @AhmadTurani 238 = 2 x 119

Comment: Ohh it is regular price